# Explode array in a table

Tags: php, arrays

I have this type of array:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [a] => BANANA
    [b] => 975
    [c] => 57
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [a] => COCONUT
    [b] => 7
    [c] => 7
  )
)
```

For each value I want to have something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="text-right no-border"><strong>BANANA - 975 %</strong></td>
    <td>57</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="text-right no-border"><strong>COCONUT - 7 %</strong></td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

How to do that please.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This should be a simple task if you learn how to use a `foreach` and string concatenation. Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php foreach($array as $value): ?>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="text-right no-border"><strong><?php echo $value['a'] . ' - ' . $value['b'] . '%' ?></strong></td>
    <td><?php echo $value['c'] ?></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

One of a million of solutions could be done using **heredoc** syntax.

### Code:

```
$my_html_document = "";
foreach($arr as $fruit=>$data) {
  $my_html_document .= <<<HTML
<tr>
  <td colspan="4" class="text-right no-border"><strong>{$data['a']} - {$data['b']} %</strong>      </td>
  <td>{$data['c']}</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>\n
HTML;
}

echo $my_html_document;
```

### Output:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="4" class="text-right no-border"><strong>BANANA - 975 %</strong>    </td>
  <td>57</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="4" class="text-right no-border"><strong>COCONUT - 7 %</strong>    </td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer

```
 $items=Array (
  [BANANA] => Array (
     [a] => BANANA
     [b] => 975
     [c] => 57
)
  [COCONUT] => Array (
    [a] => COCONUT
    [b] => 7
    [c] => 7
)
)
 $str='';
 foreach($items as $item){
      $str=$str."<tr>
        <td colspan='4' class='text-right no-border'><strong>".$item["a"]." - ".$item["b"]." %</strong>  </td>
        <td>".$item["c"]."</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>";
 }
 echo $str;
```

Comment: why not just `$str .= "<tr>...`, why not `<td>{$item['c']}</td>` (or 'a' or 'b')? it's more elegant, right ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this .. .

```
<?php

    $array = array(
                'banana' => array(
                            'a' => 'Banana',
                            'b' => 975,
                            'c' => 57,
                    ),
                'coconut' => array(
                            'a' => 'coconut',
                            'b' => 7,
                            'c' => 7,
                    ),
            );




    foreach($array as $value) { 
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="text-right no-border"><strong><?php echo $value['a'] . ' - ' . $value['b'] . '%' ?></strong></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['c'] ?></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```